# fedora pcl and ros

Tags: ros, pcl, fedora, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I just tried to compile a project using PCL under my Fedora. I am using ROS indigo but I also have jade in case. They both are compiled from source.

I'm hitting this error while compiling :

```
CMake Error at /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_jade/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pcl" with any of
  the following names:

    pclConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pcl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "pcl_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "pcl" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I have PCL installed on my machine :

```
Installed Packages
pcl.x86_64                                  1.7.2-8.fc23    @fedora
pcl-devel.x86_64                            1.7.2-8.fc23    @fedora
pcl-doc.noarch                              1.7.2-8.fc23    @fedora
pcl-tools.x86_64                            1.7.2-8.fc23    @fedora
```

And compile a small project under pcl outside of ROS works.

I tried adding places to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

```
echo $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/jade_ws/devel:/home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/source_jade/install_isolated:/usr/include/pcl-1.7:/lib64/cmake:/lib64/cmake/pcl
```

Linking directly to PCLConfig.cmake but it did not change a thing.

Any help on this appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225769/fedora-pcl-and-ros/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2016-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I really hate it when I find my answer only after I asked a question :|

Anyway if someone wonders it's because I still had :

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  geometry_msgs
  pcl
  pcl_ros
```

in my CMakeLists.txt

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0